# Why do I have to instantiate a python deque of namedtuples as a list?

Tags: python, namedtuple, python-collections

I have a queue of nodes that I need to have an upper and lower bound to them, so I have a named tuple called QueueEntry.

```
QueueEntry = collections.namedtuple('QueueEntry', ('node', 'lower', 'upper'))
```

When I instantiate a deque with the named tuple inside a list:

```
bfs_queue = collections.deque([QueueEntry(node, float('-inf'), float('inf'))])
```

and not:

```
bfs_queue = collections.deque(QueueEntry(node, float('-inf'), float('inf')))
```

Comment: Because `deque` takes an iterable (you can pass in a tuple, list, etc) https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Comment: Why would you want to use the last version? A deque is a sequence of objects, not a single object.

Answer (score 1):

The input to a *deque* is an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), so any iterable data structure will suffice:  list, tuple, set, dict, etc.

Alternatively, you can attach an object directly using the *append()* or *appendleft()* method:

```
QueueEntry = collections.namedtuple('QueueEntry', ('node', 'lower', 'upper'))
bfs_queue = collections.deque()
bfs_queue.append(QueueEntry(node, float('-inf'), float('inf')))
bfs_queue.append(QueueEntry(another_node, 0, 0))
```

Hope this helps :-)